# UITextView not scrolling horizontally in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, scroll, uitextview, xcode4.3

I have tested this with a simple project with one `UITableView` controller with static cells, added 4 or 5 `UITextView` to individual cells leaving the defaulted lorem ipsum text in , run the project.

You will see that the scroll works vertically but not horizontally.

Any ideas how to get it to scroll left/right ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code that handles those cells just use the following.

```
[myTextView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:YES];
```

Or you can set the same property on the Attributes Inspector for the UITextView on the part related to its Scroll View.